# Aspnetdb.mdf exception when calling method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a page where the admin can edit users . The code that i have is :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageUsers.aspx.cs" Inherits="SiteStiri.Administration.ManageUsers" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Repeater ID="FilteringUI" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate> 
             <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkFilter" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' CommandName='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>

             </asp:LinkButton> 

         </ItemTemplate> 
        <SeparatorTemplate>|</SeparatorTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:GridView ID="UserAccounts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
         <Columns> <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName"/> 
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" /> 
             <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsApproved" HeaderText="Approved?"/> 
             <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsLockedOut" HeaderText="Locked Out?" /> 
             <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsOnline" HeaderText="Online?"/> 
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment"/> 

         </Columns> 

    </asp:GridView>


</asp:Content>
```

the main page(i am following the tutorial first before i make things and i want )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SiteStiri.Administration
{
    public partial class ManageUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindUserAccounts();
                BindFilteringUI();
            }
        }
        private void BindUserAccounts()
        {
            UserAccounts.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
            UserAccounts.DataBind();
        }

        private void BindFilteringUI() { 
            string[] filterOptions = { "All", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",
                                         "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
            FilteringUI.DataSource = filterOptions; 
            FilteringUI.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

The code behind the page.

When i run it i get the following error

```
An exception of type 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Default Membership Provider must be specified.
```

What must be done here, how can i specify the Default Membership Provider and what is that ?

```
Extended error eport:
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Default Membership Provider must be specified.
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.InitializeDefaultProvider(Boolean initializeDefaultProvider, MembershipSection settings)
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Provider()
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords)
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers()
       at SiteStiri.Administration.ManageUsers.BindUserAccounts() in d:\ProiecteVisual\SiteStiri\SiteStiri\Administration\ManageUsers.aspx.cs:line 23
       at SiteStiri.Administration.ManageUsers.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\ProiecteVisual\SiteStiri\SiteStiri\Administration\ManageUsers.aspx.cs:line 17
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

And here is the Web.config :

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration> 
   <system.web> 
     <authorization> 
       <allow roles="canEdit" />
        <deny users="*"/>
     </authorization> 
   </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

From what i've read i must add something to the web config ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx) on how to correctly configure the membership provider.

In short - you need to set defaultProvider in membership section:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="SqlProvider" 
                    many more settings here...
                />
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeap, I will add that you can just add `<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">` withouy specifying weather it is `SQL`, `AD`, or other provider.

Comment: Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. I get this wheni add that. Must i install something ?

Comment: Are you using these settings in your root application Web.config file? Are you getting this error using IIS Express, IIS or Web development server?